# My python/selenium program is only 111 lines long. What are these errors for line 193 and 429? Using visual studio if it makes any difference

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual 
 studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 429, in main
    run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 266, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 236, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
      File "C:\Users\kryst\source\repos\Hamoq Project\Hamoq_Project.py", line 33
    driver.get("http://poshmark.com)
                                   ^
```

Comment: The little `^` is pointing at the error, looks like you forgot the closing quote on the string.

Answer (score 0):

Those error messages are referencing lines in the python modules 'runpy.py', '**main**.py', and 'cli.py'.

They are referencing parts of the modules to give you reasons for why your line of code is producing an error.

The actual error is in your line of code, which is the very last error message:

```
File "C:\Users\kryst\source\repos\Hamoq Project\Hamoq_Project.py", line 33
    driver.get("http://poshmark.com)
```